# in Excel - How do concatenate a text field with a date field

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I looked at the answers for "How to concatenate string with DATE()?" and 
the related questions.  They did not answer my question.  I am trying to concatenate

"009285"    + "Health Management Alt Path" + "2/20/2015"

and have it look something like this

"009285 - Health Management Alt Path (2/20/15)"

I can do the first 2 with this --> =CONCATENATE(A30," - ",B30)
When i do

=CONCATENATE(A30," - ",B30, " ", C30),

I get 
009285 - Health Management Alt Path 42055

Comment: @msw Can you elaborate?  As I see the OP is trying to program in excel a formula that concatenates a date and is having difficulties.  the OP has demonstrated what has been tried, what the current output is, and what the desired output is.  Why is this off topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround the date cell with a `TEXT` formatter:

```
=CONCATENATE(A30," - ",B30," ",TEXT(C30,"(d/mm/yyy)"))
```

You can pick any format for the date